# Can't use !$ in script?

Tags: bash

Just wondering why this is not working

```
#!/bin/bash 

ls /bin
ls !$
```

I expect to run `ls /bin` twice, but the second one raises errors as `!$` was not interpreted

Did I miss something, or `!$` only work in command line?

I couldn't find relevant part in `man bash` (on mac)

Comment: Although there is a solution is this really the best way to achieve this in a script? history is disabled by default for a reason when you run non interactively - a long script is going to spam the .bash_history file. Not saying it wasn't worth asking this, but just that if you're thinking of using this in a script, is this really the best way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[History](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Facilities) and [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) are disabled by default when the shell run non-interactively.

You need:

```
#!/bin/bash 

set -o history
set -o histexpand

ls /bin
ls !$
```

or:

```
SHELLOPTS=history:histexpand bash script.sh
```

it will affect all bash instances that `script.sh` may run.

Comment: careful with SHELLOPTS, it will affect that `bash` that runs `script.sh`, but also all the other `bash` instances that `script.sh` may eventually run (like other `bash` scripts...).

Comment: And it _won't_ affect any _other_ `bash` instance that runs your script.

Comment: I think this answer would improve if @StéphaneChazelas's comment is edited into it.

Answer (score 7):

The sane thing to do would be

```
ls /bin
ls $_
```

or

```
set ls /bin
$*
$*
```

or

```
c='ls /bin'
$c
$c
```

Caveats: it's worth remembering that each of these comes with some pitfalls. The $_ solution only captures the last single argument: so `ls foo bar` will leave $_ containing just `bar`. The one using `set` will override the arguments (`$1`, `$2`, etc). And all of these as written will work, but when generalized to more complex commands (where escaping and whitespace matter), you could run into some difficulties. For example: `ls 'foo  bar'` (where the single pathname argument `foo  bar` contains *two* or more spaces, or any other whitespace characters) is not going to behave correctly in either of these examples. Proper escaping (possibly combined with an `eval` command), or using `"$@"` instead of `$*`, might be needed to get around those cases.

Comment: +1 for an answer that is portable and doesn't abuse a bashism intended to make interactive use easier. (As an aside, bash's desire to interactively expand exclamation marks in the default setup is something I find counterintuitive as a user of other shells, and _counterproductive_ because it always screws me when I'm trying to do some complicated shell command).

Comment: Although as written at this moment, I was hesitant to give it the +1 due to the issues beginner shell scripters will likely have when trying to generalize it to more complex commands. I suggested an edit to at least add a caveat paragraph explaining the possible pitfalls thereof.

Comment: @mtraceur: it's not portable, only work in bash, zsh, ksh (if two command are not in the same line). Work in dash, mksh only when interactive

Comment: @cuongim: Sorry, I was perhaps too carelessly general. The `$_` way is not portable, you are right. The `set` approach works in non-interactive dash, and with the `${1+"$@"}` (plus zsh global alias) trick should be general, although I vaguely remember that `set` has a history of not being perfectly portable with some (old?) shells. The define-a-variable-holding-the-command-and-then-eval-it approach, especially using proper escaping and an actual `eval` command, is completely generally portable as far as I know.